# Why aren't my images from local folder loading?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load some images in my React App from a local folder called `images`. It's in the `src` folder. Right now there are only 2 images in there for testing purposes, but eventually there's going to be many.

First what I do is define an images array:

```
  const [loadImages, setLoadImages] = React.useState([{image:'images/kitten.jpg'}, {image:'images/penguin.jpg'}]);
```

Since I'm working with konva I define Image:

```
  const URLImage = ({image}) => {
    const [img] = useImage(image.src);
    return (
      <Image
        image = {img}
        x = {image.x}
        y = {image.y}

        offsetX = {img ? img.width / 2 : 0}
        offsetY = {img ? img.height / 2 : 0}
        draggable
      />
    );
  };
```

Then I try to load them all like this:

```
 {loadImages.map(image => (
  <img id="img" className="img"
  src={image.image}
  width="200"
  height="200"
  draggable="true"
  onDragStart={(e) => {
    dragUrl.current = e.target.src;}}
/>
))}
```

Then I also tried to see if an image from the images folder would load up if I simply did this:

```
<img src='images/kitten.jpg'></img>
```

But I still get the image is missing symbol:

[missing image symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dVH0.png)

What am I doing wrong & how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should import images from the images folder

```
import imageone from './images/3.JPG'
```

then you can

```
<img src={imageone}></img>
```

[image]

**Without importing image** then you can do some think like this

```
 <img src="./images/3.JPG"></img>
```

Comment: I know, but the problem is, if I'm going to have tens or maybe even more images, that would be a little problematic.. Is there a way to import all images at once, instead of one per one?

Comment: you can try  <img src="./images/3.JPG"></img>

Comment: @Ninini.are you still facing issue

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to load all the images. Loading them like that will be very draining when I have a folder of tens/hundres of images.

Comment: okay.not sure about how your scenario works.lets some one might help you to solve your issue